# liferay c3p0 apparent deadlock! on HSQL

Tags: java, liferay-6, hsqldb, jboss5.x

After compiling the source code of liferay 6.0.6 and deploy them to jboss 5.1.0 GA, I got the following error when I started the jboss.

```
2012-07-04 03:47:11,847 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.DialectDetector] (main) Using dialect org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
2012-07-04 03:48:31,054 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-1) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1aee7e -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2012-07-04 03:48:31,093 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-1) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1aee7e -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@1b2eecb (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@5b66d0 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@baf34f (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@1bbd74c
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@133c07e
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@a2a139
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@106cc7d
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@15b47ff
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@1d3e63b
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@b035a8
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,jboss]
        org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcDatabaseMetaData.getTables(Unknown Source)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnectionNoQuery(DefaultConnectionTester.java:185)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:62)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(AbstractConnectionTester.java:67)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:368)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:310)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,jboss]
        org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcDatabaseMetaData.getTables(Unknown Source)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnectionNoQuery(DefaultConnectionTester.java:185)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:62)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(AbstractConnectionTester.java:67)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:368)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:310)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,jboss]
        org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcDatabaseMetaData.getTables(Unknown Source)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnectionNoQuery(DefaultConnectionTester.java:185)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:62)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(AbstractConnectionTester.java:67)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:368)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:310)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1999)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

    2012-07-04 03:49:31,104 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-1) Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@1b2eecb (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().
    2012-07-04 03:49:31,104 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-1) Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@5b66d0 (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().
    2012-07-04 03:49:31,104 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-1) Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@baf34f (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().
```

I googled on the web and got to know that it is related to a c3p0 issue. see [this link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2386237) and [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=947246&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=apparent%20deadlock%20c3p0&sid=). I follow the instructions and try to make the configuration changes in `$LIFERAY_HOME/portal-ext.properties`

```
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
```

or

```
 jdbc.default.acquireIncrement=5
 jdbc.default.maxPoolSize=100
 jdbc.default.minPoolSize=10
 jdbc.default.numHelperThreads=10
```

but it didn't work.

Any suggestion ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this Liferay Issue?
http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-11779

Anyway, you could check [this thread](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5645944/maximized)

Hope it will help.